# Can selenium RC travels different domain in one test

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

If there is a one case that on open a yahoo.com page through selenium and on the click on any link on the home page of www.yahoo.com .it takes me to www.twitter.com page  it opens in new page.
Can selenium  RC execute test on twitter.com now &  after completion the test can selenium rc control go back to yahoo.com page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can, you need to execute test using browsers with elevated security privileges, like *chrome with firefox.

Comment: I am explaining the scenario by code….. _Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium( localhost, 4444,"*chrome", "http://www.yahoo.com"); _selenium.open("http://www.yahoo.com"); _selenium.waitForPagetoLoad("30000") _selenium.click("Twitter") _waitForPagetoLoad("30000"); // now it is on Twitter.com home opned in new window... // I have to check the presence of XYZ text on www.twitter.com home page /* here it is failing.. _selenium.isTextPresent("XYZ"); // again I have to come on yahoo.com page. _so goBack() will not work ..   Please explain me on this Thanks in advance..

Comment: when twitter is opened in a new window, u would have to first select it using selectWindow, you may pass windows title to it. once done with twitter, get back to Yahoo using selectWindow again

Comment: So here is it treated as popup .isn't it.